# Cheaper Contiki-style trips than Contiki

Tags: budget, australia, southeast-asia, group-travel, socializing

I want to go on a Contiki-style trip while I'm young enough to do so.

However, I looked at Contiki's web site, and found the prices a little bit high. For example, [Beaches and Reefs (Start Cairns)](http://www.contiki.com/destinations/australia/tours/421-beaches-and-reefs-start-cairns-new) is from A$2292 for 14 days, which is A$163 per day.

Are there alternatives that are like Contiki, but are less expensive?

Ideally, I'd like something that is a little bit [bogan](http://thingsboganslike.com/2009/10/23/8-contiki-tours/) (doesn't have to be extremely bogan), has a high proportion of people in their twenties or thirties, some of whom are female and single, and located in Australia or somewhere a cheap flight away from Australia (for example Bali in Indonesia).

Comment: Honestly it's cheaper and easier to meet people if you solo-travel and stay at party hostels.  Look on hostelworld/bookers and choose the hostel with the highest 'atmosphere' rating.  I've met people who have been unlucky on Contikis or Top Deck and had duller tour groups, or full of couples, whereas if the hostel you pick sucks a bit for atmosphere, just move to the next one :D

Comment: I think this is much too broad as a question. I would assume it will be closed if you do not narrow it down to something more concrete.

Comment: Is the problem that there are too many Contiki-style trip operators? If so, is there a specific word or phrase for Contiki-style trips?

Comment: If you would at least define a destination...

Comment: @uncovery I did so in the last sentence.

Comment: @MarkMayo I think you should make your comment an answer.

Comment: @WW. possibly, but as it didn't directly answer the question it felt better as a comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Although I can vouch for how awesome Contiki is, I can understand that the price-point is higher than you'd spend on your own.

As Mark Mayo pointed out, it's really easy to find where the party is at in Australia. Nearly all of the top-rated hostels found on HostelWorld will be a party with a bar and sometimes a club. I stayed at Base Hostel in Melbourne and the place was pretty crazy every day of the week. If bunk-beds are not your thing, most of these hostels have private rooms as well which might be more convenient for bringing in "guests".